# Probability Of Birthday Months

Tags: probability

> In a class of 20 students, what is the probability that at least one will be born in november or december?

Using the complement we can look at $P(\overline A)=(\frac{10}{12})^{20}$  so $P(A)=1-(\frac{10}{12})^{20}$.

If we want to find $P(A)$ directly we need to use inclusion-exclusion? why is it not $P(A)={20*2*12^{19}\over 12^{20}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, consider the event $D=\{\text{a student has birthday either in November or December}\}.$ Then it is true that $p = p(D) = \dfrac{2}{12}$.

As for me, my suggestion is to approach this problem through the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Let $X$ be the random variable which expresses the number of the students that have birthday either in November or December. More specifically, $X\sim \mathcal B(n,p)$, where $n=20$ and $p=p(D)$.

Suppose that **exactly** $k$ students have birthday either in November or November. Then it holds:
$$P(X=k)= \dbinom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Since we want **at least** one student have birthday either in November or December, it is sufficient to calculate:
$$P (X\ge 1) = 1 - P(X=0),$$ 
where we take the first formula you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to look where are the intersections that I need to reduce by calculating it directly

Comment: Think about $k=2$. $P(X=2)$ expresses the probability exactly 2 students (not a specific pair) have birthday either in November or December. Doesn't  this count as "intersection"? Also, think about $P(X=20)$. It expresses the probability that all 20 students have birthday either in November or December. All students share the $D$ property. Basically, what we are looking for is this sum:
$$P = P(X=1) + P(X=2) + \cdots + P(X=20).$$